# Import specific variables from file without computing others

Tags: python, python-import

Let's say I run

```py
from variables import b
```

and `variables.py` is as follows:

```py
a = [i ** i for i in range(10000)] # or any other computation that takes a long time
b = 1
```

Is there a way to import `b` without computing `a`?

I was thinking that I could add an if statement like this:

```py
if (variable_being_imported() == 'b'):
  b = 1
else:
  a = [i ** i for i in range(10000)]
```

I know I can define functions and run the functions after importing them, but is there a way without defining functions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try in `variables.py`:

```
def main(var):
    if var == 'a':
        a = [i ** i for i in range(10000)] 
        return a
    else:
        b = 1
        return b
```

And import it this way:

```
import variables
b = variables.main('b')
```

Comment: I don't think this question is the same as the one marked. I want to be able to import `a` or `b`. If I wrap the a inside an if name == main, then I won'd be able to import it. I want to be able to import a or b, and not compute one of them based on what is being imported.

Comment: @NathanDai Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I knew that I could define functions and run them. I'm assuming there's no way to accomplish the same thing without importing the function.